# Admin role update Impacts

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

There was some unassigned role for admin in carbon console which I updated and assigned to Admin but I am not sure what role was that now since there are thousands of roles for admin.
Recently when we were testing our environment we are not able to create application using curl and seeing this error in api-manager logs when trying to create application for testing purpose.
Can these role changes be related to this error. Please let me know as we are stuck on testing our environment due to this issue.

```
 ERROR - SubscriptionsApiServiceImpl Tier Unlimited is not allowed for API/API Product org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.model.ApiTypeWrapper@76314748. Only [Bronze] Tiers are allowed.
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIMgtAuthorizationFailedException: Tier Unlimited is not allowed for API/API Product org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.model.ApiTypeWrapper@76314748. Only [Bronze] Tiers are allowed.
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.utils.RestAPIStoreUtils.checkSubscriptionAllowed(RestAPIStoreUtils.java:310) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util_6.6.163.33.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.impl.SubscriptionsApiServiceImpl.subscriptionsMultiplePost(SubscriptionsApiServiceImpl.java:299) [classes/:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.SubscriptionsApi.subscriptionsMultiplePost(SubscriptionsApi.java:76) [classes/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179) [cxf-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) [cxf-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) [cxf-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) [cxf-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:265) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:298) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:217) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) [tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:273) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:86) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.4.0.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve_1.4.0.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:103) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve_1.4.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.0.44.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.0.44.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.0.44.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.0.44.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.0.44.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:124) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.0.44.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

Is there any way to find what roles were last updated or anyway to rollback any recent roles related change for admin. Need some help plz someone take a look

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find this information in the `audit.log` which is located in `<APIM_HOME>/repository/logs`. You should see a log like below when you assign a new role to a user.(Depending on which option you use)

```
# Here the user admin was assigned to the role Internal/system 
INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator=admin@carbon.super Action=Update-Users-of-Role Target=Internal/system Data={"New Users":["admin"]} Outcome=Success

OR

# Here the testRole was assigned to the user admin. 
INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator=admin@carbon.super Action=Update-Roles-of-User Target=admin Data={"New Roles":["testRole"]} Outcome=Success
```

Answer (score 0):

Above error is due to the subscription issue. Your API or API Product only has bronze tier as a subscription policy. You are trying to subscribe to the API with an unlimited subscription policy.

Comment: Thanks so much, It worked. We updated the subscription policy to Unlimited and Application was able to subscribe.